# A throttle not calling the last throttled argument

Tags: javascript, throttling

Context: I was writing a simple throttle under the task of a [javascript tutorial](https://javascript.info/task/throttle)

Task: write a throttle that works like this:

```
function f(a) {
  console.log(a)
};

// f1000 passes calls to f at maximum once per 1000 ms
let f1000 = throttle(f, 1000);

f1000(1); // shows 1
f1000(2); // (throttling, 1000ms not out yet)
f1000(3); // (throttling, 1000ms not out yet)

// when 1000 ms time out...
// ...outputs 3, intermediate value 2 was ignored
// P.S. Arguments and the context this passed to f1000 should be passed to the original f.
```

Here's my solution. Strangely, it works fine when I run it step-by-step in a debug console but not otherwise. Any idea why and how to fix it? (I assume it has to do with `setTimeout`?)

```
function throttle(f, ms) {
  let isCoolDown = true,
  queue = []

  function wrapper(...args) {
    queue.push(args)

    if (!isCoolDown) return

    isCoolDown = false
    setTimeout(function() {
      isCoolDown = true
      if (queue[0] !== undefined) {
        f.apply(this, queue.slice(-1))
        queue = []
      }
    }, ms)

    return function() {
      f.apply(this, args)
      queue = []
    }()
  }
  return wrapper 
}
```

Comment: Google `debounce js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug at this line:

```
f.apply(this, queue.slice(-1))
```

The `.slice` method will return an array. Since the `args` is an array, the result of `queue.slice(-1)` would be something like:

```
[ [1, 2, 3] ]
```

Instead, you can change it to:

```
f.apply(this, queue.slice(-1)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1) swap `isCoolDown = false` and `isCoolDown = true`

2) you don't need a queue, only one call has to go through the others get discarded with throttling

---

```
 function throttle(fn, ms) {
   let throttle = false;
   let timer;

   return wrapper(...args) {
     if(!throttle) { // first call gets through
        fn.apply(this, args);
        throttle = true;
     } else { // all the others get throttled
        if(timer) clearTimeout(timer); // cancel #2
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
          fn.apply(this, args);
          timer = throttle = false;
        }, ms);
     }
  };
}
```